# Which is better style: "is linked" or "it is linked"?

Tags: writing-style

Does *it* improve an English sentence's style? Which of the following is "more English"?

> The table exists and **it** is linked to a correct server.
>
> The table exists and is linked to a correct server.

Where can I read about this?

Comment: This is really just a stylistic choice that could largely depend on the *full* context. Why, for example, do you refer to it as *"**the** table"*? Usually that would be because "the" table has previously been referenced, in which case it might be rather superfluous/odd to point out that it "exists" at all. I think as it stands this is subjective, and Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: The former is more emphatic, acting like a rebuttal to an unfounded accusation. There's no real fixed rule as to which of the two better, it depends on what you want to emphasize or how strong you want to be in the statement.

Comment: The context is as follows. A comment in a program notes that the table with the name "Projects" (**the** table) already exists and therefore it needs not to be created. It is a linked table, and it's connected to some server (one of a few, no matter which one, so **a** was used) that is up and running now, and thus there is no need to re-link it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would write the first as

```
The table exists, and it is linked to the correct server.
```

(Note the substitution of the definite article `the` for the indefinite article `a`. This is because you are using the word "correct," which implies that there is one and only one definite "correct server"). The comma is more a matter of style than grammar, but it is common (but not necessary) when you have a full clause as is the case in the first example.

I would write the second as

```
The table exists and is linked to the correct server.
```

Both are accurate; for me, as an American, the second reads a little bit better.

Comment: Please see my comment about the context. I wholeheartedly accept your note about commas in compound sentences.

Comment: I am so grateful for this mini-lesson from more knowledgeable members! Thanks a lot, dear FumbleFingers, Oldcat outis nihil!